How to replace @Query JPQL sql with jpa repository method name?
I have two entities
data class MetaConfigEo(
    @Id
    val id: String? = null,

    val config: Config,
)

data class ConfigEo(
    @Id
    val id: String? = null,

    val config: Config,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var configType: ConfigType,

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meta_config_id")
    var metaConfig: MetaConfigEo? = null,
)

And I have the following Jpa Repository
@Repository
interface MetaConfigRepository : JpaRepository<MetaConfigEo, String> {

@Query(
    "SELECT mc FROM meta_config mc JOIN config c ON mc.id = c.metaConfig.id " +
            "WHERE c.configType = :configType"
)
fun findMetaConfigByConfigType(configType: ConfigType): MetaConfigEo?

Is it possible to replace the given mthod in the JPA repository with a query which works with the name instead of specifying a JPQL Query in @Query?

can you elaborate the requirement?

I want to get the MetaConfig by providing the configType, like in the findMetaConfigByConfigType Method, without using the @Query Annotation, but solve it by providing a proper method name, so JPA generates the query.

Yes, Spring data supports Property Expressions to traverse nested properties.
Try this:
fun findByConfigConfigType(configType: ConfigType): MetaConfigEo?

or
fun findByConfig_ConfigType(configType: ConfigType): MetaConfigEo?


To achieve this feature using the method name in Spring-Data JPA, you need to make sure that you are following the correct naming conventions that Spring-Data JPA use to generate the query automatically. In your case, you want to find a MetaConfigEo by the configType of the associated ConfigEo. You can get this by using following:
@Repository
interface MetaConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<MetaConfigEo,String> {
 
         MetaConfigEo findByConfig_ConfigType(ConfigType configType);
}

